# C++ access a certain range of indices of a vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

I think I got an easy problem, but I can't find the solution anywhere.

I have a string vector containing a lot of words. say the 1st element has **5** letters, but I only want to access the first **3** letters. how do I do this?!

```
std::string test_word = "hou";
std::vector<std::string> words = {"house", "apple", "dog", "tree", ...}

if (test_word == /*(words[0].begin(), words[0].begin()+3)*/) {
...
}
```

what is the correct grammatical way to write it?

**EDIT: solution**

```
std::string test_word = "hou";
std::vector<std::string> words = {"house", "apple", "dog", "tree", ...}

for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
   for (int j = 1; j <= words[i].size(); j++) {
      if (words[i].compare(0,j, test_word) == 0) {
      ...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is inefficient. Comparing the strings beyond the length of test_word is unnecessary. Notice that when j > test_word.size() your if statement will always be false. For example, when i=0 and j=4, words[0].compare(0, 4, test_word) will never return 0 because 'hous' is not equal to 'hou'. Are you trying to find all strings in words that share the same prefix (ie. test_word)?

Comment: @putnampp - yes, you are right, that is a little problem. but I don't know how to check for it. it kinda goes back to my original question how to select a certain range of a vector. (I'm coming from _Matlab_ and there it is very easy). **I could do this:** `if (words[i].substr(0, j).size() <= test_word.size())` before the other _if_, but the code even runs 5 times longer then :(

Comment: @putnampp - and also yes, I'm checking every possible prefix of the words in the vector if it is equal to the test_word. and test_word is always different in length (depending on input), that's why I need the 2nd loop to really check for `ho==`, then `hou==`, then `hous==`, then `house==`, then `ap==` ... and so on.

Comment: Simple observations: 1) words[i].substr(0,j).size() will always be j! 2) you're checking 'h'=='hou', 'ho' == 'hou', 'hou'=='hou', 'hous'=='hou', 'house'=='hou'. Of the 5, only the third test is true. If this is the desired logic, then you can simplify your code and remove the inner loop entirely. Just perform 'if( words[i].compare(0, test_word.size(), test_word) == 0)'

Comment: If you're wanting to perform some task for each of 'h'=='h', 'ho'=='ho', 'hou'=='hou' (ie. each of the common prefixes between a word in words, and the prefixes of test_word), then the inner loop is necessary. But you can change its condition to j <= std::min( words[i].size(), test_word.size()). This eliminates unnecessary suffix checking.

Answer (score 3):

```
if( words[0].compare(0,3, test_word) == 0)
```

Should avoid doing unnecessary memory allocations.

Comment: hmm, I was about to ask that. I just hit _compare()_ while reading about the new learned _substr()_ . you may think this is more efficient?

Comment: Short answer: would expect compare to be more efficient. Long answer: compare should be optimized to positionally compare the two strings until the first mismatch, or at most the end of match length (in this case, 3). Conversely, substr may return a copy of the first three characters of words[0]. Although, since the comparison length is small, and you are looking for exact equal, an optimizing compiler may be able to perform some memory comparison tricks making any performance differences unnoticeable.

Comment: thank you very much! I've extended my original question by your suggestion. it works the way I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

> I only want to access the first ..

Using `std::string::substr` is a convenient way of doing this, but it might result in a heap allocation. So if you need performance or want to stick **exactly** to your goal and only *access* these elements, then you should use `std::equal` from `algorithm`:

```
std::equal(words[0].begin(), words[0].begin()+3,
  "text which is not shorter than 3 elements")
```

And there is also the `compare` member function, as putnampp showed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are specifically interested in a `std::string` you can use [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)

```
if (test_word == words[0].substr(0, 3))
```

As [@DanielJour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116364/daniel-jour) mentioned in the comments, you may also use `std::equal`

```
if (std::equal(begin(test_word), begin(test_word) + 3, begin(words[0]))
```

Comment: Note that `substr` might result in a heap allocation. You may be better off using `std::equal` if this is inside a tight loop.

Comment: @DanielJour Good point, why aren't you posting an answer demonstrating  how it works?

Comment: thank you for the quick answer! that might very well do it. this will probably also work with my correct code, where I run a for-loop, checking like "_test_word == h_", then "_test_word ==ho_", then "_test_word == hou_" .. so, simply `if (test_word == words[0].substr(0, j))` with `j` being the loop parameter .. :)

Comment: If you're running this in a loop as described, then you really should use `std::equal` or the compare member function to avoid possible allocations. (I'm on mobile, which is why it takes a while to write an answer)

Comment: ah, I think I understand. `substr` will virtually create a new string, so allocating new space. if `equal` doesn't do this, then it will be better since I'm running through every word of the string and then even every letter of the words.

Answer (score 1):

> *"say the 1st element has 5 letters, but I only want to access the first 3 letters. how do I do this?!"*

You can apply the [`std::string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) function to refer to the first 3 letters:

```
if (test_word == words[0].substr(0,3)) {
```